# Why is REST API get call going to the wrong method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 `get` methods in my API controller, one which accepts no arguments and one which accepts an integer argument.

The path for the API page is `/api/contact`.   When I navigate here, the page displays as expected.

However, when I change the path to `/api/contact/4` to try to invoke the `get` method which accepts an integer argument, the code instead just invokes the same get method without any arguments.  I know this by putting in breakpoints and debugging.  What is going wrong?

```
public PhoneInfo[] Get()
{
    return contactRepository.GetAllContacts();
}

public PhoneInfo[] Get(int phn)
{
    return contactRepository.GetMessages(phn.ToString());
}
```

Comment: did you register the route template? if not it is probably expecting the int value in the query string e.g. /api/contact?phn=4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WebApi** works based on reflection this means that your curly braces {vars} in your global.asax/routing configuration must match with the same name in your methods.

By default your global.asax will look like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
                     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                     defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Therefore to match the above where `id` exists as a var the url is `api/contact/{id}` the method needs to be declare like this:

```
   public string Get(int id)
       return "test";
   }
```

While in your example your are changing the default name of the parameter from `id` to `phn` causing WebApi not being able to find your method.

Another option can be to use the `RouteAttribute`:

```
 [Route("api/contact/{phn}"), HttpGet]
 public string Get(int phn)
   return "another value";
 }
```